# How can I tell CSS :not() selector to affect all child nodes?

Tags: css, sass

Please see this minimum example

```css
.global :not(.guard) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="global">
  <p>I'm outside guard</p>

  <div class="guard">
    I'm inside guard.

    <div>
      <hr>

      <p>
        I'm a block inside guard.

      </p>

      <p>
        I want to black color too.
      </p>

      <p>
        How can I achieve it?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a style(SCSS) like this

```
.global {
  :not(.guard) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I want anything inside the node with `.guard` class name's color not to be affected by `color: red;`

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

If I've correctly understood the effect you are trying to achieve, you can implement it with the following two selectors:

```
.global {
  color: red;
}

.global .guard {
  color: black;
}
```

In this case, you really don't need the `:not()` pseudo-selector at all.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.global {
  color: red;
}

.global .guard {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="global">
  <p>I'm outside guard</p>

  <div class="guard">
    I'm inside guard.

    <div>
      <hr>

      <p>
        I'm a block inside guard.

      </p>

      <p>
        I want to black color too.
      </p>

      <p>
        How can I achieve it?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Since `color` is inherited, please use another rule for `<p>`:

```css
.global :not(.guard) {
  color: red;
}

.global :not(.guard) p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="global">
  <p>I'm outside guard</p>

  <div class="guard">
    I'm inside guard.
    <div>
      <hr>
      <p>
        I'm a block inside guard.
      </p>
      <p>
        I want to black color too.
      </p>
      <p>
        How can I achieve it?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```