# Is it possible to make a Guard class name in CSS that prevent global style? Global style can be modified

Tags: css

Please see this minimum example.

Say if I have my own version `reset.css` in the global scope.

```css
/* My Reset CSS */
button {
  color: red;
}
```

And all my markup will be affected by my Reset.css.

Now, I want to prevent some markup from being affected by my Reset.css

```html
<button>I'm a button with Reset CSS</button>

<div class="guard">
  <button>I don't want to be affected.</button>
</div>
```

I know I can use `!important` to override Reset.css again.

But I want to create a `guard` class, everything lives inside the `guard` class will not inherit anything from Reset.css

I have tried `:not()` selector, but it doesn't work.

```css
/* Not working */
:not(.guard) button {
  color: red;
}
```

How can I modify my own version of Reset.css to achieve this?

```css
/* My Reset CSS */
button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>I'm a button with Reset CSS</button>

<div class="guard">
  <button>I don't want to be affected.</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you can edit your old question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64909217/8620333 if the solution provided aren't suitable

Comment: I think my old question isn't clear enough, and can leads to different answears.

Comment: edit it isntead of asking a new one, don't ask multiple question and create more confusion.

Comment: I didn't describe my old question clear enough, so there are different answers, and I've already accepted people's answer, editing old answer is not helping.

Comment: you are not obliged to accept answers and you can still edit your old question and comment on the actual answers so they can review your question again. It will help everyone to keep everything in the same question instead of keeping a partial not clear question and ask a new one